# do not want to add value to list Python using Pyserial

Tags: python, mysql, list

I wasn't sure how to word this question appropriately. My problem here is i am using the PySerial package to read values from a port and am sending 5 values to a list. I have a condition where when the value 10000 shows, send a timestamp to a database, i want that to happen but not to add that value to the list. here is the code.

```
while i<5:
   data=ser.readline().strip()
   print data
   i=i+1
   if int(data)<30:
        frame = cap.read()[1]
        pic = str(frame)
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Camera (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,img BLOB,PRIMARY KEY(ID))")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Camera (img) VALUES(%s)",(pic,))
        conn.commit()
        cv2.imwrite(filename='img.jpg', img=frame)
        arduinoData.append(data)
   elif int(data)==10000:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Alarm (time) VALUES(now())")
        print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
        arduinoData.append("4")
   else:
        arduinoData.append(data)
#Drop previous table of same name if one exists
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SensorData;")
print("Finished dropping table (if existed).")

# Create table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE SensorData (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,value VARCHAR(40),PRIMARY KEY(ID));")
print("Finished creating Sensor table.")


# Insert some data into table
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO SensorData (value) VALUES (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s);",[arduinoData])
```

to try and solve the problem for now when the value 10000 is detected I am appending the value '4' to the list so I won't get an SQL exception error for not inputting 5 values from the list into the database. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You might want to make a code that will generate the `query` depending of your actions. What you are actually doing will work if the data "shape" is always the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The shape of the data always stays the same, it's sensor data from an arduino project of mine. I'm converting the values into an int to compare them. If the sensor triggers an alarm that's when the value 10000 get sent to my python script and if it detects that I want the timestamp to be added, which it does with this code, I just don't want to substitute a hardcoded value to my list instead of a normal value from the sensor. I don't think I'm explaining this well